# Working with data in java

Tags: java, analysis

I've been using a formula for some time to try to find value in spreads for sports betting and done this by basically creating my own spread and comparing to what bookies offer and would like to automate the process.

I've written some code in java which will do the maths on the data I give it and I'm looking for a way to populate the input data either from a database or from an xml file I create but i'm quite new to programming.

Say for example if I pick two teams to compare. For each team I need a list of the teams they played, how many points each team scored in total, how many points each team conceded in total and how many games each team played so I can run the maths on those figures and I have no idea where to start. Could anyone help me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: I hear the internet is full of information.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've defined your problem (how to start), and also listed the information you need to get started (compare two teams, points, previous games, conceded points, etc). Are you sure you don't know how to start?

For a point in the right direction - I recommend creating a test case where you select two teams, give them some sample data for their previous games, points scored and conceded, and start working on the structure of your program.

This question lends itself too much to personal opinion and personal experience, and that makes it difficult to give you definitive answers without looking at any code or a program layout.

Give it your best effort and reply back with what you come up with, that will be much easier to critique and offer suggestions to.

Comment: thanks clipsett. i've created a test case where i simply define the variables i am working with and it works, i just don't know how i'd go about putting all of the possible data in to a file (my friend suggested an XML would do the trick) and reading that data to populate the variables. that's what i'm stuck with.